# how do i typeshift <class 'sympy.sets.sets.FiniteSet'> to int

Tags: sympy

I want to typeshift a value from a sympy solveset to be an int.

I try this:

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')

a = solveset(Eq(x+radii[0],2*(-x+radii[-1])),x)

a = int(a)
```

I get this error:

```
int(gearAdjust(radii))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'FiniteSet'
```

my desired result is for this code to just make a an int.

Comment: `int` is a basic python function that takes makes one number, with a inputs as listed in the error message.  It isn't "type shifter".  Show us `a` (before your int try).  Look up `FiniteSet` in the sympy docs, https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/sets.html#finiteset

Comment: The code as shown is incomplete and doesn't run because it refers to variables that are not defined.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is an object of type `FiniteSet`. You can convert it to a list and extract its element:

```py
int(list(a)[0])
```